# How to copy all files recursively excluding folders into one destination folder?

Tags: mac, terminal, cp

I have several folders like `/music/1/a.mp3` and `/music/2/b.mp3`

All of the file names themselves are guaranteed to be different.

Is there a way, probably using the Terminal, to copy these files to `/musicTemp/` excluding the folders?

In other words, the result of the two examples above should be:

```
/music/1/a.mp3
/music/2/b.mp3
```

into:

```
/musicTemp/a.mp3
/musicTemp/b.mp3
```

Comment: Does Finder provide an option to search for files recursively?  If yes, search, select all, and drag to your destination.  I know that's a good option on other OSes.

Comment: That's so obvious I just facepalmed. All files are .m4a and Finder lets me limit to just /music/. Thanks!!!

Comment: Just to add an alternative: `find /music -name "*.mp3" -type file -exec mv {} /destination_dir \;`

Comment: @Hennes: `cp` not `mv`.  Otherwise that should work.

Answer (score 8):

The `find` command will find all files of the specified pattern (-name), in this case a specific file type: `*.mp3`. `-exec` makes all following arguments to find to be taken as arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered (at the end, with literal escape to prevent expansion by the shell). In this case, the command we wish to execute is a file copy (`cp`) on files that match pattern (`{}`) and copy those files to `/destination_dir`. This command should do the trick:

```
find /music -name "*.mp3" -type file -exec cp {} /destination_dir \;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have [installed Bash 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55412/cd-to-a-directory-just-by-typing-its-name/55424#55424), you could add `shopt -s globstar` to .bash_profile and run this:

```
cp /music/**/*.mp3 /musicTemp/
```

Comment: Not sure what `shopt..` is necessary for as this works without mods, also with `mv`..  Thanks anyhow the `**` is new to me :)