# Using Find & Copy recursively with verbose, stats or progress possible?

Tags: linux

Regarding the article below:
[How to copy all files recursively excluding folders into one destination folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/562527/how-to-copy-all-files-recursively-excluding-folders-into-one-destination-folder)

Is there a way to make this call and also show `--stats` and/or `--progress`?

does `cp` allow for these options?

im generally very new to linux, sorry in advance.

-Jinda

Answer (score 0):

`cp` and `find` both don't know anything about the work that is still ahead.

But there are workarounds. In order to get a per-file progress bar, one possibility is to replace `cp` with `pv` (you may need to install this tiny tool).

Assuming that files reside in ~/old and you want copies in ~/new, you could do something like:

```
export SOURCE=~/old
export DEST=~/new
find $SOURCE -type f -print -exec bash -c 'pv $1 > $DEST/$(basename $1)' $0 {} \;
```

Note however that this way permissions are not conserved, and permission on all newly created files is governed by the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

How this trick with `pv` works under the hood is described in greater detail in https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp. In the answers to this question you'll find also a number of alternatives to `pv`.